# Change log-in password for Windows 10 Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-10

My login password is not the same password as my Microsoft Account password. I'd like to change my login password to something else, but the only thing I've been able to locate is how to change the Microsoft Account password. Where do I go to change the password actually used to log in to the user account on the machine?

Comment: Are you 100% positive the computer is still linked to the Microsoft Account?  If your not positive, enable the default Administrator account, and simply change the password of the local account then link the account to your Microsoft Account again

Comment: I mean, how am I supposed to know for sure? If I go to the account page by clicking my name in the top-left part of the start menu, it says my e-mail address under my name rather than "Local Account", and as I already mentioned, when I click change password, it asks me to change the Microsoft Account password, not the login password. (And yes, they differ and I *want* them to differ. I just want to be able to change it.)

Comment: You never said you wanted them to be different, or never it in a way, that it was clear.  I thought what you were saying, they were different, and you were wondering the reason.  You can't have a profile linked to a Microsoft Account, and not use the password to the Microsoft Account to access the profile, the intention of this feature is to provide SSO functionality to Windows.  *Given the response you provide, I am taking the hint, and walking away from this question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft Account to login to Windows 10

1. then they are one and the same account
2. you can't change password for this account Locally

What you described in your question is not how it's suppose to work, you have a sync issues which could be why your passwords are not the same. I have had this happen to me and you do want to make sure they are in Sync otherwise you could get locked out of the system. or you should

[Create A New Local User Account In Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/226540/how-to-create-a-new-local-user-account-in-windows-10/)

### Fixing Password Sync Issues for Microsoft account

1. Make sure your are connected to Internet
2. Change password on live.com give it sometime to sync
3. Reboot
4. Login with new password

Comment: I don't want to change my Microsoft Account password. I want to change the login password. And I certainly don't want them to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

So if you don't want them to be the same, here's what you have to do:

1. Unlink your user account with your Microsoft account (this can be done from your account settings) and make your user account a "local" account
2. Change your password

While your account is linked with your Microsoft account and your computer is connected to the Internet, your password will always be the same. By making your account a local account, it's then not linked to your online account.